# Rails: Dependent delete_all not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 5 models. `Server`, `Platform`, `Game`, `RetentionReport`, `DataReport`. And I am trying to use `:dependent => :delete_all`, but it wont work. Here are my models.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :platforms, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :game_id, :company_id

  belongs_to :game
  has_many :servers, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :region, :device_type, :platform_id, :platform_server_id

  belongs_to :platform
  has_many :gm_data_reports, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :gm_retention_reports, :dependent => :delete_all

  delegate :company_id, :to => :platform

  validates :platform_server_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :platform_id}
end

class DataReport < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :server
end

class RetentionReport < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :server
end
```

Whenever I run `Game.delete_all` in the terminal, nothing gets deleted not even the `Platforms`

Comment: Try `dependant: :destroy`.

Comment: I tried this and same result

Comment: Sorry, I'm being stupid--it's `dependent`, not `dependant`. Try that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete_all` does not trigger `call_backs`.

If you have `Game.destroy_all` it will do what you want.

You can use `:dependent => :destroy` or `:dependent => :delete_all` in the association declaration. The former will run callbacks in the association  and the later one does not.

Comment: Yes but neither of these solutions work. Nothing is destroyed or deleted if I implement either

Comment: when you execute `Game.destroy_all`, wht is the result?. Does it destroy all the games?

Comment: Just tried Game.destroy_all again, and it destroys all `Games` all `Platform` all `Server`. But it does not destroy `DataReport` or `RetentionReport`

Comment: if you want to destroy all just use `dependent: :destroy` after each association. Use `delete_all` when you want something different